# How to create a script in linux to display an error?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the code below, but whenever I run it and enter an incorrect name it doesn't show the error message, it just goes blank.

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
if [ "$name" = "" ]
    then echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "
    read name
else
    echo "Name '$name' is not in directory"
fi
grep -i $name ~uli101/2015a/phonebook
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the code: The "error message" is shown when $1 is not empty. You probably wanted something like

```
if ! grep -i "$name" ~uli101/2015a/phonebook ; then
    echo "Name '$name' is not in directory"
fi
```

Comment: For good measure you can also write the message to stderr instead of stdout with `echo >&2 "...."`